# Shiny textInput to sting used in SQL

Tags: r, shiny

I have a textInput in a Shiny app for the user to write three character product codes separated by a comma. For example: F03, F04, F05.

The output of the textInput is used in a function calling a sql script. It will be used as a filter in the sql statement, eg

```
sqlfunction <- function(text){

sqlQuery(conn, stri_paste("select .... where product_code in (", text, ");"))

}
```

To convert the textInput to a string that I can use in the sql statement, I have used

```
toString(sprintf("'%s'", unlist(strsplit(input$text_input, ","))))
```

This works and converts the textInput to 'F03', 'F04'. 'F05' however when used in the sql only the first code, 'F03', is used in the search despite using *product_code in ()*. The data returned is only those with a product code F03.

How do I get all three codes, if not more, written in textInput into a string to use in the sql clause?

Andrew

Comment: Can you include some sample values for `input$text_input` ?

Comment: (1) SQL injection, don't just `paste` your code (https://xkcd.com/327/). Better to use *at least* something like `glue::glue_sql`, but more likely something like `DBI::dbBind` or at least `DBI::sqlInterpolate` (I much prefer `DBI::dbBind`). https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/. (2) Using `"'%s'"` is good, would be slightly better using either `sQuote` or (preferred) `DBI::dbQuoteString`.

Comment: Your premise looks good, as to why the `in (...)` is not working sounds like the DBMS is not working in the expected way or the data does not vary like you think it does. Is it safe to assume that you can find data with the other value when looking specifically for them?

Comment: I suspect the @Jrm_FRL's answer might be on to something. You might consider using `trimws(unlist(strsplit(...))` to remove leading/trailing whitespace.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is what I suspect is what you want:

```
text_input = "A,B,C"
in_clause <- paste0("'", unlist(strsplit(text_input, ",")), "'", collapse=",")
sql <- paste0("WHERE product_code IN (", in_clause, ")")
sql

[1] "WHERE product_code IN ('A','B','C')"
```

Here I am still using your combination of `unlist` and `strsplit` to generate a string vector of terms for the `IN` clause.  But then I use `paste` with `collapse` to get the output you want.

Comment: You really shouldn't use `paste0("'",...,"'")`, it'll break with malformed strings. I suggest `DBI::dbQuoteString` or `sQuote` at a minimum, as both of them handle embedded single-quotes.

Comment: @r2evans There is an even bigger problem here: SQL injection.  If any of the contents of the `text_input` could be coming from the outside, e.g. from user input, then there is a chance that a malicious SQL fragment could be injected into the OP's database.  So, I'm not worried about malformed strings so much.

Comment: Agreed, as my [first comment 5min ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60099603/shiny-textinput-to-sting-used-in-sql#comment106294331_60099603) suggested. All I'm saying is that since we know the data is going into a SQL statement, it's not good form to suggest a literal concatenation of single quotes.

Comment: I strongly agree with @tim-biegeleisen, read https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/ if you need to be convinced !

Comment: I *literally* have that link in my comment above.

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly when combined with Jrm_FRL suggestion to remove all white spaces.

Answer (score 1):

if your input is

> F03, F04, F05

with whitespaces between commas and next value, the statement gives :

> select .... where product_code in ('F03', ' F04', ' F05');

Note the whitespaces. Then the values 'F04' and 'F05' are not found.

What if the input is `'F03,F04,F05'` ? (without spaces)

Comment: I think a good solution would be to use `trimws` to remove it instead of requiring the user to not add them to begin with.

Comment: (I am only pointing out what's wrong in this particular case, but, indeed, there are several ways to build your sql request more safely and more elegantly)

Comment: Thank you it was a combination of this and the paste0() solution by Tim Biegeleisen

Answer (score 0):

I'll combine the important components of the other answers and discussion into one suggested answer. Feel free to accept one of them, they had the ideas first.

As Jrm_FRL said, it is possible that whitespace around the commas is being preserved in your script, which should not match in the SQL.

```r
toString(sQuote(unlist(strsplit("hello, world, again", ","))))
# [1] "'hello', ' world', ' again'"
###              ^--       ^--  leading spaces on the strings
```

Some options:

1. If you think it is important for the user to be able to intentionally introduce whitespace around the commas (meaning: at the beginning or end of a string/pattern), then your only hope is to *instruct* the user to only use whitespace when intended.
2. Otherwise, you can use `trimws`:

   ```r
   toString(sQuote(trimws(unlist(strsplit("hello, world, again", ",")))))
   # [1] "'hello', 'world', 'again'"
   ```
3. `strsplit(..., ",")` can be incorrect if the user has quotes to keep things together. You might consider using `read.csv`:

   ```r
   trimws(unlist(read.csv(text="hello, \"world, too\", again", header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)))
   #           V1           V2           V3 
   #      "hello" "world, too"      "again"
   ```

   This is not perfectly compatible with option 1 above.

Second, as Tim Biegeleisen and Jrm_FRL both agreed, you are specifically prone to SQL injection here. A malformed (either accidentally or intentionally) search string from the user can at best corrupt *this query's results*, at worst (depending on connection permissions) *corrupt or delete the data* in the database. (I strongly suggest you read https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/.)

Ways to safeguard this:

1. Don't manually add single-quotes around your data: if a string includes a single-quote, it will *not* be escaped and will cause at best a SQL error.

   ```r
   toString(sQuote(trimws(unlist(strsplit("hello'; drop table students; --", ",")))))
   # [1] "'hello'; drop table students; --'"
   ### this query may delete the 'students' table
   ### notice that `sQuote` is not enough here, it is not escaping this correctly
   ```

   Instead, use `DBI::dbQuoteString`. While I believe most DBMSes use the same convention of single-quotes (and your question suggests that yours does, too), it can be good practice to let the database driver determine how to deal with literal strings and those with embedded quotes.

   ```r
   toString(DBI::dbQuoteString(con, trimws(unlist(strsplit("hello'; drop table students; --", ",")))))
   # [1] "'hello''; drop table students; --'"
   ###          ^^ this is SQL's way of escaping an embedded single-quote
   ### this is now a single string, allegedly SQL-safe
   ```
2. Instead of including the strings into the query, use `DBI::dbBind`, though admittedly you'll need to include multiple binding bookmarks (often but not always `?`) based on the length of your values vector.

   ```r
   val_str <- "hello, world, again"
   val_vec <- trimws(unlist(strsplit("hello, world, again", ",")))
   qmarks <- paste(rep("?", length(val_vec)), collapse = ",")
   qmarks
   # [1] "?,?,?"
   qry <- paste("select ... where product_code in (", qmarks, ")")
   out <- tryCatch({
     res <- NULL
     res <- DBI::dbSendStatement(con, qry)
     DBI::dbBind(res, val_vec)
     DBI::dbFetch(res)
   }, finally = { if (!is.null(res)) suppressWarnings(DBI::dbClearResult(res)) })
   ```

   The use of `?` varies by DMBS, so you may need to do some research for your specific situation.

   (While I used `tryCatch` here to "guarantee" that `res` will be cleared on exit, this pattern is a little more robust than doing it without. If part of the query or binding fails without the `finally=` part, then it could leave the connection in an imperfect state.)